# How do you "start over" with a subversion repo?

Tags: svn

I don't know what I did, but I cannot commit my project to Google Code anymore.  I get the following error:

```
svn: Commit failed (details follow):
svn: Directory '/Users/jeff/Desktop/svn_repos/project/mac/myapp.app/.svn' containing working copy admin area is missing
```

Then I try:

```
svn add mac/myapp.app
svn: warning: 'mac/myapp.app' is already under version control
```

Something is screwed up... How can I reset my subversion for all the files, then re add them to svn?

Thank you.

Edit: Also, for the future, how do you replace a .app file and keep it under subversion version control?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's actually not too hard:

1. Do a fresh checkout of the code into a new directory.
2. Use a merge tool to merge your specific changes - not the .svn directories - from your old working directory into the new one.
3. Commit from the new directory.

From then on, you should be able to commit, update, whatever from your new working directory. Once you're confident that you have the changes, blow away the old directory at your convenience.

Comment: I have a TON of specific changed files.  I'd like to just tell subversion to copy all files from my other folder, and replace the current ones, keeping them under version control.  There shouldn't be any merging changes. What does this mean for step 2?

Comment: If you're 100% sure that your edited files are the latest and greatest and you don't need to do internal merges, use a merge tool that you can select whole files. It will handle copying them over the ones in your fixed repo.

Answer (score 1):

I would save the file with the edits, delete the directory with the corrupt .svn dir and update the working copy from the base dir. This should restore it to a usable state, then you can replace the working copy version of your .app file with the one with your latest changes.

If the files have the same name, that should not have any problems. If you want to rename use `svn rename`.

Comment: Removing the `.svn` subfolder causes svn to consider the folder as unversioned. If you then try a `svn update` it will complain with "svn: Failed to add directory 'myapp.app': an unversioned directory of the same name already exists". Instead, he should just delete "myapp.app" entirely (not just the .svn subfolder) and let it be restored by an `svn update`.

Comment: @Wim I meant the entire dir that has the corrupt .svn so that it can be restored.